# How would I express Last Row + 10?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a code that counts the rows in column A and then runs this array formula in the corresponding rows in other columns, I am wondering if it's possible to have the code run +10 more times than the last row.

For example if there are only populated fields in Column A2 and A3, I would like this code to run 12 times from J2-J14 so it takes the last row +10 if this is possible?

Thank you in advance :)

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Range("J" & i + 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A))+1, """"), ROW(A" & i & "))),"""")"
    Range("K" & i + 1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D))+1, """"), ROW(A" & i & "))),"""")"
Next i

For i = 2 To 50
    Range("L" & i).Formula = "=IF(J" & i & "="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J" & i & "))"
Next
```

Comment: **1.** You do not need to enter the formula in a loop. You can enter the formula in one go to all the relevant cells. For example `Range("A1:A14").Formula = "=Something"`. **2.** And to include the 10 rows the code can be `Range("A1:A" & LastRow + 10).Formula = "=Something"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you for your time & advice, unfortunately each time the Macro is ran there will be different rows in "A" populated, for example sometimes there will be 40 populated fields and the code will need to run to A50.

Comment: `unfortunately each time the Macro is ran there will be different rows in "A" populated` But that is what `lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` is there for :) It will give you updated rows every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim LastRow     As Integer

'// ADD 10 to lastrow
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 10

'// formulas
Range("J2:J" & LastRow).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A))+1, """"), ROW(A2))),"""")"
Range("K2:K" & LastRow).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$D:$D, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$K:$K, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\[O.xlsx]S'!$A:$A))+1, """"), ROW(A2))),"""")"

'// formulas
Range("L2:L50").Formula = "=IF(J2="""","""",SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,J2))"
```

If A2 is fixed then use $A$2 for small function

Comment: The entire formula you provided did not work as it should however the ".Row + 10" bit has helped me achieve what I wanted, thank you! :)